# CSS Gradient Text issue

Tags: css, gradient

I'm trying to replicate this: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect however I can't seem to get it to work, although I've used the same code..

This is my HTML:

```
<h1><span></span>Sign Up</h1>
```

And CSS:

```
h1 {
font-family: arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 24px;
position: relative;
color: #a2a2a2;
}

h1 span {
background: url(gradient.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
display: block;
margin-top: 2px;
width: 100%;
height: 21px;
}
```

And this is what happens:

[image: The Problem]

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your "gradient image".

You're supposed to use a gradient containing only the same colour as the background, but with the opacity of the gradient starting at around 0% and ending at around 100% (your choice exactly what numbers).

I've loaded the [demo image](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/css-gradient-text/images/gradient-white.png) into Photoshop, and made it wider so you can see what it should look like **in Photoshop**:

[image]

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for clearing that up. However, if the text colour is different to the background color, is this method not possible?

Comment: The text colour is irrelevant. The problem is if the *gradient colour* and *background colour* are not exactly the same.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry I get it now! Long day.. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

ehmm...your text is outside the span?

And besides that, the gradient they use is a white gradient on a white background. You are using a black gradient on a white background :) Might be the difference

Comment: yeah saq that later on. But fix the gradient image and it will work!

Answer (score 1):

You should make your gradient file use the same color as the background of your page as the 'paint' and keep the rest transparent